# Different ways to use local variables from HTML / Javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Recently I have been doing a lot of work in PHP and I have become familiar with how it works. I stand by what I have said before; That every problem has an endless amount of solutions. So that is what I am after, solutions that solve the same problem.

In this case, I want variables/references to values from localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("user", "bananaflakes55");
localStorage.getItem("user");
```

and directly include them in PHP files. Now I have found out that using echo have a variety of uses, for example:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.replace("' . $refclinklogin . '"); </script>';
```

Granted that the value there are on serverside -> client side. In this case I want similar solutions that necessarily wont require me to create a GET or POST, with HTML elements like forms, that connect these.

To sum up, I want solutions that can bring values from local and session storage, to PHP. Bring forth some funky ideas, if possible. From what I have read it is a tricky one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This website is not a coding service, so please include research and solutions you've tried, so the community can help you with your problem, instead of simply asking for solutions.

Comment: Well If you spent even a few seconds reading, instead of continuing the rant of negative attitude this site is infested with, you would notice that a solution would be to create a form in HTML and bring values via POST/GET. This is a solution, and the most common one. However, as stated.. I am looking for other solutions.. IF possible. 

Welcome to my post.

Comment: But you explicitly said you don't want to use HTTP. Your only other choice is WebSockets. One way or another there must be communication from each client back to the server over the Internet.

Comment: @Pointy I was afraid of that, hence why I said 'If possible'. I dont have experience using WebSockets but from what I can tell it likely is not an easier solution, but a more complex one.

Thanks for the response thought.

Comment: Hmm.... While I'm not entirely sure on how I would solve it in practice, my first instinct if I were to try something like this would be to try using cookies. It looks like you can set cookies in javascript and read them in PHP (though I assume not on the same pageload, but like I said, I haven't tried it myself).

Comment: You could use AJAX. It involves a HTTP request but you don't need a form or any HTML, and it's easier than websockets

Comment: P.s. I'd avoid using terms like "smart" and "elegant" on here when asking for solutions though...those are subjective terms and not everyone defines them the same way or thinks that the same solutions are elegant. It puts your question at risk of being closed for being opinion based. Instead just describe what you're trying to achieve and any problems you're having. :-)

Comment: ... oh yeah, I probably misunderstood the question and thought you didn't want ANY kind of GET/POST request. But if you just want to avoid forms, then yeah, definitely use Ajax or fetch.

Comment: Thanks ADyson and olafmoriarty, I will look into AJAX and/or fetch for possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Even if i understand what you want, process sould be running from PHP to client rather than the reverse.

With this in mind, a light solution can be something like that :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("POST", 'localStorageToSession.php', true);

    request.onload = function () {
        let saveResponse = request.responseText;
        // if you want a callback or use some script return

    }
    let data = "jsonLocalStorage=" + JSON.stringify(window.localStorage);

    request.send(data);
}) ;
```

Once the page is loaded, send all localStorage parsed in json to a PHP treatment (here called `localStorageToSession.php`).
So you can convert localstorage as $_SESSION. Something like that :

```
$_SESSION['jsLocalStorage'] = json_decode($_POST['jsonLocalStorage'], true) ;
```

Then you can use $_SESSION['jsLocalStorage'] in your backend treatments. Don't forget to add session_start() on all your files.
You can save the xml request in a function and call once localStorage is updated).

Even if that solution works, i don't recommand it if you have to deal with safety informations like passwords or user special access.

Comment: Well you are indeed onto something with the special user access. The idea behind the question is so save a local/session value that will be used as an access token to the user that has it. This value will be evaluated throughout the use of the service, and compared to another value stored in a database. This is just another security measure for logins and registration of accounts. And it is technically running from PHP to client, I just need the values from client side to be evaluated on server side, hence why I am looking for solutions that can bring the client side values from client->server